# Function int() rounding towards negative infinity (floor) or zero?

Tags: python, int, floor

I see [Why is -1/2 evaluated to 0 in C++, but -1 in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22030342/why-is-1-2-evaluated-to-0-in-c-but-1-in-python) says integer division rounds towards infinity in Python, namely, `floor` is applied to the result.

I thought `int(value)` would also do something like `floor`, while I get `int(-1.5) == -1` in practice, which was expected to be `-2` in my mind.

So question is: why rules are inconsistent between `integer division` and function `int()`? Is there any reasonable explanation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int()` removes the decimal component; it doesn't do any rounding. From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int):

> If x is floating point, the conversion truncates towards zero.

For turning a `float` into an `int` this is entirely logical behaviour. This is *not* division, flooring or otherwise.

The `//` floor division operator otherwise clearly *does* floor, not truncate. In Python 2, for two integer operands, the `/` division also floors. The [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations) again:

> the result is that of mathematical division with the ‘floor’ function applied to the result

where [`math.floor()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.floor) is documented as:

> Return the floor of *x* as a float, the largest integer value less than or equal to *x*.

I see no inconsistency here; division floors, turning floats to integers truncates.

Comment: Maybe it's not inconsistent with the docu, but why should it be desirable? I get int(-1.0/49*49) = 0, but int(-1.0/50*50) = -1. Any reason why int() should not do rounding?

Comment: There is an explicit [`round()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round) for rounding. `int()` explicitly takes the integer part of the float value, it doesn't round. It's a different operation.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `round()` with `ndigits = 0` is more close to what you're expecting. But `round()` doesn't return an integer, but a float: see [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round)