# Odd rounding issue

Tags: python, python-2.7, floating-point, int, rounding

I was just coding something when I noticed something odd:
`2/3` returns 0, which is logical, because that's 0.6666666666666666, which gets rounded towards 0, because its an int.
`int(2/3.0)` returns the same, because `int(0.6666666666666666)` returns 0.

now:
`-2/3.0` returns -0.6666666666666666 which is logical, but here comes the part that is confusing me,
`int(-0.6666666666666666)` returns 0 (because ints round towards 0).
But `-2/3` returns -1...
Why is this?
Shouldn't this also return 0?
After all `int(-0.6666666666666666)` returns 0, so why does `-2/3` return -1?

TL;DR: `2/3 == 0`, but `-2/3 != 0`?

Best regards, Sjaak.

Comment: Now that you mention it, shouldn't 0.666666... round to 1 (rather than 0) if this is just doing normal rounding?

Comment: The true duplicate appears to be [Why is -1/2 evaluated to 0 in C++, but -1 in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22030342/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`/` **floors**, it doesn't truncate. It is not the same operation as `int()` applied to a floating point division. From the [*Binary arithmetic operations* documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations):

> the result is that of mathematical division with the ‘floor’ function applied to the result.

[`int()` truncates](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int):

> If *x* is floating point, the conversion truncates towards zero.

Flooring always rounds down, so for negative numbers that'll round away from 0.

It should be noted that the [`-` unary operator](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#unary-arithmetic-and-bitwise-operations) has a higher [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) than the `/` division operator, so the expression is parsed as `(-2)/3`, not `-(2/3)`.

Comment: In many __other__ languages `/` will truncate (i.e. round towards zero) and then `(-2) / 3 == -(2 / 3) == -0 == 0`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: It's a choice each language makes. Python and Ruby floor while Java, C, C# and FORTRAN truncate.

Comment: I’ve cleaned up the comments about what makes a duplicate; I’m happy to talk about such things on Meta or in chat.